# F# comparing lambdas for equality

Tags: serialization, lambda, f#, equality

I would like to try and compare F# lambdas for equality. This is, at first inspection, not possible.

```ml
let foo = 10
let la = (fun x y -> x + y + foo)
let lb = (fun x y -> x + y + foo)
printfn "lambda equals %b" (la = lb)
```

which generates the error

> The type '('a -> 'b -> int)' does not support the 'equality' constraint because it is a function typeF# Compiler(1)

However, and surprisingly, it is possible to serialize lambda functions.

```ml
open System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
open System.IO
let serialize o =
    let bf = BinaryFormatter()
    use ms = new MemoryStream()
    bf.Serialize(ms,o)
    ms.ToArray()

let ByteToHex bytes = 
    bytes 
    |> Array.map (fun (x : byte) -> System.String.Format("{0:X2}", x))
    |> String.concat System.String.Empty

let foo = 10
let la = (fun x y -> x + y + foo)
let lb = (fun x y -> x + y + foo)

let a = serialize la 
let b = serialize lb

printfn "%s" (ByteToHex a)
printfn "%s" (ByteToHex b)
printfn "lambda equals %b" (a = b)
```

which suggests that if they can be serialized they can be compared. However, inspection of the byte stream for this example shows two bytes where there is a difference.

[image]

Is there possibly a strategy to solve this problem by intelligently comparing the byte arrays?

Comment: What do you understand by two functions being equal?  For example, would you expect the functions `fun x y -> x + y` and `fun x y -> y + x` to be equal?

Comment: An interesting language based on what it means to meaningfully have canonical representations of code is being built at https://unisonweb.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From an equivalence perspective, functions aren't meaningfully serialized.

*Curryable* functions in F# are implemented as derived from `FSharpFunc`.

```
let la = (fun x y -> x + y + foo)
```

would be implemented as an instance of the following class (in equivalent C#):

```
[Serializable] class Impl : FSharpFunc<int, int, int>
{
    public int foo;
    Impl(int foo_) => foo = foo_;

    public override int Invoke(int x, int y) =>
        x + y + _foo;
}
```

What binary serialization captures would be the full typename and the value of foo. 
In fact if we look at strings in the byte stream we see:

```
test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Program+la@28
foo
```

...where `la@28` is the name of our derived class.

Where the byte stream for `la` and `lb` differs is the name of the implementing class. The implementations of `la` and `lb` could be entirely different.

You could, for instance, change `lb` into `let lb = (fun x y -> x * y + foo)`, and the result would be same for both runs.

---

You can however, do this with [Code Quotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/code-quotations):

```
let foo = 10
let la = <@ fun x y -> x + y + foo @>
let lb = <@ fun x y -> x + y + foo @>

printfn "Is same: %b" (la.ToString() = lb.ToString()) //true
```

F# also supports `Expression<Func<>>` (C#'s expression trees) - which is also a valid avenue for comparison.